# Mongoose $slice and select not working together

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I use

```
const data = await User
.findOne()
.slice("followers", 10)
.select("followers")
.exec() 

console.log(data)
```

slice and select do not work together.  I can use them each on their own with no problems but when I put them together it only uses the last one.  Are you not allowed to use slice and select together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I put them together it only uses the last one. Are you not allowed to use slice and select together?*

The `select()` and `slice()` both are projection functions, So yes last projection function will overwrite the previous function, see a similar issue in GitHub mongoose [issues 5450 in comment](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5450#issuecomment-318725295).

This `.slice("followers", 10)` is equal to `.select({ "followers": { "$slice": 10 } })`.

It should require inclusion or exclusion fields in projection if you want to select only single `followers` field in result.

**If you want to select only `followers` field with the slice operation try,**

```
.select({ 
  "_id": 1, // inclusion (1) or exclusion (0) anything you want
  "followers": { "$slice": 10 } 
})
```

Result:

```
{ "_id": "6088e3e9e22a94c6df69448f", "followers": [... 10 elements] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must using $slice for select nested array and $slice in optinal find() function. Ex:

```
const data = await User
    .findOne(condition, {followers: {"$slice": [skip, limit]}})
    .select("followers": {"$slice": [skip, limit]} )
    .exec()
```